# Обновление Apache Solr

Tags: java, apache, update, solr

Как правильно инициализировать CoreContainer имея на руках только solrHome и solrConfig пути до файлов?

в 4 версии apache solr это выглядело так:

```
CoreContainer coreContainer = new CoreContainer(solrHome.toString(), solrConfig.toString());
```

И вроде бы логично и просто, но вот в шестой версии обновились конструкторы для CoreContainer и теперь необходимо пилить NodeConfig. Проблема в том, что это невозможно сделать, имея только 2 параметра на руках, а нужно задать и solrHome и solrConfig. Есть кто обновлял apache solr 4.1 -> 6.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В новой версии, то бишь в 6.1.0 они перелопатили метод доступа до конфигураций самого солара и его ядер. строчки:

```
CoreContainer coreContainer = new CoreContainer(solrHome.toString());
```

будет достаточно. Этот путь должен быть до [solr.xml](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Format+of+solr.xml#Formatofsolr.xml-Definingsolr.xml), в эту же папочку кладем настроенное ядро(dir, с [core.properties](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Defining+core.properties) файликом внутри). Вот собственно всё :)